# How can I use Powershell as my tramp-encoding-shell?

Tags: windows, powershell, emacs, plink, tramp

First I start up eshell then I enter the command `cd /plink:<user>@<host>:/home/`

then I get this error message

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator.
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

I am trying to connect with plink (which is in my path), also after going through the *Messages* buffer I found this.

> Couldn't find local shell prompt for (C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe)

I'm 90% sure that this is because the cmd has been disabled on my machine, because when I try the same setup on a different computer, where I know the cmd is enabled, everything works.

I've modify my `.emacs` file to have

```
(require 'tramp)
(set 'tramp-encoding-shell "C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowershell/v1.0/powershell.exe")
(set 'tramp-encoding-command-switch "-Command")
```

I get different results, however the results appear to be scrambled nonsense (the third line looks like it could be a prompt, the `\` and `>` characters are in the correct places...).

[image: emacs error]

I managed to dig up a pretty good [description](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/tramp-devel/2009-06/msg00009.html) of what `tramp-encoding-shell` is, there's also a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477035), and here is the `tramp-encoding-shell` [source/documentation](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/28caedba0f5c387d9c8e8fc8de26b5399afeb68b/lisp/net/tramp.el#L154-L178) on github.

**Update**

Here is what my screen looks like after trying to unsuccessfully open a plink connection with powershell set as the tramp-encoding-shell.

[image: fullscreen screenshot]

Comment: Windows PowerShell send you back unicode (UTF16), each character is 16 bits in this case the letter an a zero, plus the fact that the End Of Line is carriage return / line feed (0xa, Oxd) it may explain what you get.

Comment: @JPBlanc well that was part of the problem, I added `$OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding` to my powershell profile and that got rid of the garbled text, but I'm getting a "Couldn't find local shell prompt for (... powershell)" error. I think the new error might be related to the EOL thing that you mentioned.

Comment: @JPBlanc, upon further inspection it looks like [tramp knows how to handle windows style newlines](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/net/tramp.el#L507-L512).

Comment: Can you explain where you get "Couldn't find local shell prompt for (... powershell)" error, perhaps with a screenshot ?

Comment: @JPBlanc I added a screen shot of what I'm seeing. The window on the right is pulled up automatically by emacs.

Answer (score 2):

So I dont know TRAMP but the explanation of what you get is that Windows PowerShell send you back unicode (UTF16), each character is 16 bits in this case the letter an a zero, plus the fact that the End Of Line is carriage return / line feed (0xa, Oxd).

Now for *"emacs could not find local shell prompt for PowerShell"* error according to [TRAMP documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) **@Michael Albinus** advice seems to be promising.

**6.4.2 Running shell on a remote host**

Calling M-x shell in a buffer related to a remote host runs the local shell as defined in `shell-file-name`. This might be also a valid file name for a shell to be applied on the remote host, but it will fail at least when your local and remote hosts belong to different system types, like ‘windows-nt’ and ‘gnu/linux’.

You must set the variable `explicit-shell-file-name` to the shell file name on the remote host, in order to start that shell on the remote host.

**6.4.6 Running remote processes on Windows hosts**
With the help of the winexe it is possible tu run processes on a remote Windows host. TRAMP has implemented this for process-file and start-file-process.

The variable tramp-smb-winexe-program must contain the file name of your local winexe command. On the remote host, Powershell V2.0 must be installed; it is used to run the remote process.

In order to open a remote shell on the Windows host via M-x shell, you must set the variables explicit-shell-file-name and explicit-*-args. If you want, for example, run cmd, you must set:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "cmd"
      explicit-cmd-args '("/q"))
```

In case of running powershell as remote shell, the settings are

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "powershell"
      explicit-powershell-args '("-file" "-"))
```